# How to install QGIS Server Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, apache, error, qgis-server

I am new user to Ubuntu (12.04) and am trying to set up QGIS server. I have QGIS desktop installed and working.

In regards to QGIS server I have used

```
apt-get install qgis-mapserver libapache2-mod-fcgid
```

and was successful but when I try the **GetCapabilities request it fails** and also when I try start/stopping apache2 I get the error **"No Apache MPM package installed"**. Do I need to configure the apache2.conf file for this to work? Thanks for your time.

Below is example of error.

```
ben@ubuntu:~$ aptitude search apache2-mpm-
p   apache2-mpm-event               - Apache HTTP Server - event driven model   
p   apache2-mpm-itk                 - multiuser MPM for Apache 2.2              
p   apache2-mpm-prefork             - Apache HTTP Server - traditional non-threa
p   apache2-mpm-worker              - Apache HTTP Server - high speed threaded m
ben@ubuntu:~$ /etc/init.d/apache2 start
No apache MPM package installed
```

Comment: I got Apache2 working. I did 3 things, not sure which solved the problem. First I ran 'apt-get install apache2-MPM-worker'; second I edited apache2.conf and removed the hash in front of ServerRoot; thirdly started apache2 with sudo (root) command at start, ie: '$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start'. When I got to http://localhost I get the "It Works!". However when I run the QGIS Server GetCapabilities request (http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities) I get the Internal Server Error.

Comment: Still getting Internal Server Error when I run get Capabilities request.

Comment: Given Ubuntu 12.04 is not yet fully supported with QGIS I have gone back to 11.1 - The GUI is not nearly as smooth though! Thanks for reading. This could be deleted if you like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have faced the same problem: "Internal Server Error with Ubuntu 12.04".
Everything looked OK to me (I even run successfully a perl fcgi script to test FCGI in my apache server). I continually got an Internal Server Error when I run a get Capabilities request. The apache log file said "Premature end of script headers: qgis_mapserv.fcgi".

The problem was solved when I included a previous QGIS generated project file into the cgi folder (in my apache installation was /usr/lib/cgi-bin). 
Apparently, the qgis server searches for a project in the cgi folder and the error comes out if there is no project.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to upvote "Davichu", but I would like to commend him for helping me solve my problem through his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you. I did

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork
```

And it works.

So, I think your first thing that you did in the comment [How to install QGIS Server Ubuntu 12.04?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24335/how-to-install-qgis-server-ubuntu-12-04#comment32739_24335) is the solution.